# Any python OpenID server available?

Tags: python, openid

I'd like to host my own OpenID provider. Is there anything available in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[poit](http://yangman.ca/poit/) is a standalone, single-user OpenID server implemented in Python, using python-openid.  (It's a project I started)